# My CPU usage is shooting to 100% when I try to steam response using Langchain

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, cpu-usage, openai-api, langchain

I have created a RAG using Langchain. I'm using openai API to generate response. When i ask question without any stream my cpu usage is normal. But when I use streaming my cpu usage is shooting from 0% to 100% like:
Code without stream:

```
chat_history = []

question = input("Enter")
log_cpu_usage("Before Processing")
ai_msg = rag_chain.invoke({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
print(ai_msg)
log_cpu_usage("After Processing")
chat_history.extend([HumanMessage(content = question), AIMessage(content=ai_msg)])
```

Here is the output without stream:
Output:

```
[CPU Usage] Before Processing: 14.3%
User: Hi
Hello Faiq! How can I assist you today?
[CPU Usage] After Processing: 16.8%
[CPU Usage] Before Processing: 13.6%
User: How are you?
Thank you for asking, Faiq! As an AI, I don't have feelings, but I'm here and ready to help you with any questions or concerns you may have. How can I assist you today?
[CPU Usage] After Processing: 2.5%
[CPU Usage] Before Processing: 11.4%
```

Code for Streaming

```
chat_history = []

question = input("Enter")
answer = ""
for chunk in rag_chain.stream({"question":question, "chat_history": chat_history}):
    (chunk, end="", flush=True)
    log_cpu_usage(":")
    answer +=chunk
    chat_history.extend([HumanMessage(content = question), AIMessage(content=answer)])
```

Here is the output with streaming:

```
[CPU Usage] CPU Usage:: 13.5%
User: Hi
[CPU Usage] :: 10.4%
Hello[CPU Usage] :: 0.0%
 F[CPU Usage] :: 100.0%
ai[CPU Usage] :: 100.0%
q[CPU Usage] :: 16.7%
![CPU Usage] :: 100.0%
 How[CPU Usage] :: 100.0%
 can[CPU Usage] :: 4.8%
 I[CPU Usage] :: 100.0%
 assist[CPU Usage] :: 0.0%
 you[CPU Usage] :: 16.7%
 today[CPU Usage] :: 100.0%
?[CPU Usage] :: 100.0%
[CPU Usage] :: 0.0%
```

I'm getting lot of trouble in deployment. Can anyone help me on optimizing my cpu usage?

Comment: can you restart your system and try again?

Comment: Restarting won't help because I'm encountering the same issue during deployment. I've deployed my project on an EC2 instance and implemented a load balancer as a temporary solution, But i need to optimize my code to reduce the associated costs.